# Change chat height from certain point

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my site more responsive and one problem is the chat. If I change height of the website chat gets behind there. What are the best ways of fixing that? My best bet at the moment is removing the div above the chat where are buttons, then `calc` will work but problem with that is if I change the height it will start changing from the chat (Like it has to) but I would love to change it so it starts from the `social` panel.

Make it clear: How can I fix resizing chat height by keeping above div and start changing it from a certain point, this time `social panel`.

```css
.col-md-4 {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  height: 100%;
}

.not-logged {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.buttons {
  display: inline-block;
}

.login-button {
  width: 145px;
  height: 37px;
  background-color: #bf1c2d;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.register-button {
  width: 145px;
  height: 37px;
  background-color: #bf1c2d;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.chat-info a {
  color: #bf1c2d;
}

.chat-info {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid #ccc;
}

.chat {
  height: calc(100vh - 180px);
  display: block;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  max-height: 380px;
}

.chat-msg {
  padding: 3px 0px;
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 35%, 62% 35%, 55% 0);
}

.chat-msg>div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.chat-msg>div>span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="not-logged">
      <h4>To access the site</h4>
      <h4>Please <b>login</b> or <b>register</b></h4>
      <div class="buttons">
        <a class="login-button">Login</a>
        <a class="register-button">Register</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat-area">
      <div class="chat-info">
        <h4 style="float: right;">
          <span id="isonline">0</span> Online
        </h4>
        <h4><a href="#">Chat Rules</a></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="chat" id="chatArea"></div>
      <form id="chatForm">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here to chat..." id="chatMessage" maxlength="200">
      </form>
      <div class="social-info">
        <div class="social-header"></div>
        <div class="social-data" style="text-align: center;">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-official fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw fa-2x"></i></a>
          <br>
          <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a> |
          <a href="#">F.A.Q.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hgjv6rLg/

P.S If you downvote please tell me a reason so I could improve my post.

Comment: Use CSS `@media` queries for the different heights of the screen, here is a link [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: I need the height change automatically not by setting it.

Comment: maybe use % instead of pixels?

Comment: Could you maybe try to provide me an example on my Fiddle please :)?

Comment: I am not quite sure what exact problem you are facing. Sorry

Comment: Do you want the chat box alway stay in bottom?

Comment: *"If I change height of the website chat gets behind there. "* what does that mean? What do you mean "chat" - the input? Behind *where*?

Comment: @MichaelCoker By behind I mean if I change the height then the chat just "disappears" but I want it to change height of the chat automatically so it goes smaller if height is changed.

Comment: what chat? Is it in your demo?

Comment: Yes, it just does not work.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Do you maybe have any ideas why does the calc work when I don't have the div above that (buttons and those welcome texts)

Comment: Be sure to `@` me or I don't see your replies. Can you populate the chat with some sample data so we can reproduce the problem? I don't see the problem reproduced in your demo.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Alright, I didn't know that. Can't you see if you resize your internet window than the chat "goes away" what I want is if you resize your window (height) then the chat goes smaller.

Comment: nothing disappears when I resize the height of the window.

Comment: @MichaelCoker Open up the fiddle and change height of your browser and you can see that if you change height the `Type here to chat` goes away/under the browser.

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/hgjv6rLg/3/